# Guardar la suma de ASP.net en la base de datos

Tags: asp.net, base-de-datos

Hola yo tengo una suma en **asp.net** así:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double a = Convert.ToDouble(Numero1.Text);
    double b = Convert.ToDouble(Numero2.Text);
    double resultadosum = a + b;
    Resultado.Text = resultadosum.ToString();
}
```

Y la vista de la suma esta hecha en `aspx` necesito el resultado de la suma guardarlo en una base de datos, ya cree la base de datos y tambien añadí el modelo en `asp`.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Solo tendrías que hacer un insert a tu tabla.

```
string ConnString = "<TU Cadena de Conexion>";

string SqlString = "Insert Into TuTabla (NombreCampoBD) Values (@Parametro)";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
{
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlString, conn))
  {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parametro", Resultado.Text);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

Usas [ado.net](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-and-modifying-data)